# All AppEngine generated emails end up into SPAM

Tags: google-app-engine, email, spam

I am using app-engine to send out notification emails to myself (not even to users in this particular instance).

All of them end up in the gmail spam folder, no matter how many times I mark it as 'not spam'.

Even if a given email address (e.g. info@mydomain.com) sends a notification to itself it ends up in the spam (...).

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188884/google-app-engine-emails-going-to-spam-folder) that suggests an explanation but it doesn't really give a solution.

Is there a simple way to work around this annoying issue - at least for internal notifications - that doesn't involve acquiring certificates for my domains?

Comment: Is your application hosted on your own google apps enabled domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because it was actually mailed by **some_random_id_xyz.apphosting.bounces.google.com**, instead of directly from your own ID?  This is indicated by the "mailed-by" header in your incoming email.

One solution: instead of using your gmail id (which is probably the admin / developer account for your app), send it from **some_string@your-app-id.appspotmail.com**, and add **your-app-id.appspotmail.com** to the safe domain list (add filter: mark such mails as 'never send to spam').

Later when you have users, you can instruct them to do the same, assuming they will be subscribed to your app.

Comment: 'never send to spam' did the trick. not great but OK for what I need it. Can't believe I didn't think of that :) Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, 'never send to spam' is more of a temporary fix than a real solution.  Maybe SPF record is the answer, as suggested by @fmatheis, I will try it sometime.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you might need to add an SPF record to your DNS server.

See http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723

Answer (score 0):

Trying send using full name instead of just the email address.
e.g. full name